# What makes a name of a method equivalent to an action delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I was just experimenting and ended up with the following snippet:

```
public static class Flow {
    public static void Sequence(params Action[] steps) {
        foreach (var step in steps)
            step();
    }
}
void Main() {
    Flow.Sequence(() => F1(), () => F2());
    Flow.Sequence(F1, F2); // <-- what makes this equiv to the line above?

}
void F1() { }
void F2() { }
```

I didn't realize that a method name alone was the same as an Action.

What is making this so?

Comment: They are not actually equivalent; The latter is better, because it avoids an extra, empty method call. (which I admit might be optimized out, but still; they are not equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this is kind of what is happening in the background:

```
void Main() 
{    
    Flow.Sequence(new Action(delegate(){ F1(); }), new Action(delegate(){ F2(); }));    
    Flow.Sequence(new Action(F1), new Action(F2)); 
}
```

They're not EXACTLY equivalent, but they're very close. They would render the same results at run-time, the only difference being that the arguments in the first Sequence invocation would be an Action which invokes an anonymous method which then invokes the static methods F1 and F2; the second Sequence invocation would be an Action which invokes the static methods F1 and F2.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No worries, I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 7):

In C#, delegates are nothing more than [method pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). They can point to existing methods in a class, or independent anonymous delegate objects altogether.

This paragraph from the above link should explain what's happening in your code:

> Any method that matches the delegate's signature, which consists of the return type and parameters, can be assigned to the delegate. This makes is possible to programmatically change method calls, and also plug new code into existing classes. As long as you know the delegate's signature, you can assign your own delegated method.

That is, when resolving delegate types, what's considered are their signatures, rather than their names.

In your case, your `F1()` and `F2()` methods, taking no parameters and returning nothing, have matching signatures with the parameterless [`Action` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
public delegate void Action();
```

Therefore, they're implicitly convertible to `Action`.

If you try to pass a method with a different return type or at least one parameter, you'll get a compile-time error as it won't correspond to `Action`'s signature.

Comment: And,, using `F1` instead of `() => F1()` calls the method directly instead of adding an extra delegate around it.

Comment: @xixonia: Not very "directly", the compiler creates an instance of `Action` too, this `Action` is created from the method `F1` directly. While using `() => F1()`, the `Action` is created from an anonymous method, in which `F1()` is invoked.

Comment: @DannyChen, At least more directly than not. :) Thanks for the correction. I was worried I hadn't stated that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler uses an implicit conversion from a method group to a delegate of compatible type (in this case a void returning method taking no arguments), the method names here are irrelevent.